# Error C3016 C++ PCL and Openmp

Tags: c++, openmp, point-cloud-library

I have this error when I'm trying to build PCL `approximate_progressive_morphological_filter.hpp(139): error C3016: 'i' : index variable in OpenMP 'for' statement must have signed integral type` the .cpp file is can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qpjbxy2zi6z8gfn/approximate_progressive_morphological_filter.hpp) and the log file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yz8ggu1n38y68c7/pcl_segmentation.log). So I'm asking if anyone could please advise how to overcome this error. This is the part of the .cpp file causing that error, the first line specifically:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < input_->points.size (); ++i)
  {
    // ...then test for lower points within the cell
    PointT p = input_->points[i];
    int row = std::floor(p.y - global_min.y ());
    int col = std::floor(p.x - global_min.x ());

    if (p.z < A (row, col) || pcl_isnan (A (row, col)))
    {
      A (row, col) = p.z;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't link your stuff, please put it here. The links may become invalid, stuff put here stays.

Comment: Error C3016 is quite self explaining, isn't it? The error message exactly tells you what to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing `size_t` to `long`.

Thanks